# Weak$^*$ continous functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space (not necessarily reflexive) and let $X^{*}$ denote the continuous dual of $X$. Let $\psi:X \to X^{**}$ denote the canonical embedding of $X$ into its double dual $X^{**}$. We know that the weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ is induced by the family of continuous linear functionals $\{\psi(x): x\in X\}$.

From this, can we say that every weak$^*$ continuous linear functional on $X^*$ is of the form $\psi(x)$ for some $x\in X$? If it is, I would like to know an explanation of the answer. If not then a counter example would help. I am a beginner on this domain and know very little. So, I do not know, if this question is trivial.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a continuous linear functional on $(X^{*}, weak*)$. There exists  a basic neighborhood of $0$ in weak* topology, say $\{f\in X^{*}: |f(x_i)| <r_i, 1 \leq i \leq N\}$ such that $|F(f)| <1$ whenever $f$ lies in this neighborhood. In particular, this implies that if $f(x_i)=0$ for each $i$ then ($nf$ is in the neghborhod for each $n \in \mathbb N$ so) $|F(nf)| <1$ for all $n$. This proves that $\bigcap_i ker (F_{x_i}) \subseteq ker F$, where $F_x(f)\equiv f(x)$. An elementary lemma in linear algebra now says that $F$ is a linear combination of $F_{x_1},F_{x_2},,...,F_{x_N}$  so $F=F_x$ for some $x$ of the form $\sum c_ix_i$and this is exactly what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy. I have understood the essence of the proof. I think there is some confusion regarding small "f" and the capital "F".

Comment: I am using $f$ for an element of $X^{*}$ and $F$ for a continuous linear functional on $(X^{*}, weak*)$.  Is there a typo in my answer?  @srm99

Comment: I think it will be "whenever $f$ lies in this neighborhood @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the correction.